# Custom "valueToTree" and "treeToValue" behavior in Jackson

Tags: json, jackson

I'm trying to customize Jackson to convert between objects of classes that are not beans and JSON.  Importantly, I'm not trying to serialize/deserialize, but rather convert objects into JSON trees and back.

It there any special means of getting Jackson to do this?  Or do I just have to create a subclass to the ObjectMapper and override the "valueToTree" and "treeToValue" methods?

Thanks

I've tried looking on line, but there only appears to be customization for serialize/deserialize to /from a string.